# missing alignment guides in xcode interface builder

Tags: xcode

I am new to programming on the Apple Mac.  I have followed a programming guide supplied in the Mac Developer Library to program a basic GUI program called TrackMix.  In this program you place a textbox, a vertical slider and a button control on the view window.  Initially, on dragging the specific object, say the textbox, to the window, a set of alignment guides (dotted blue lines)  would automatically appear on the canvas when the object is dragged over it.  I dont know what has happened, but now those guides have disappeared when I execute the same action of dragging objects to the window.  When the object being dragged is over the window a small green dot, with a plus sign in it, appears on the bottom of the object.  I have carefully retraced my steps to be exactly the same as stated in the Developer Library, but still the problem persist.  Have I, perhaps, involuntarily changed some Xcode settings or what? I am at the end of my wits! PS: I am using Xcode 7.

Answer (score 1):

You have to toggle the menu item "Editor > Canvas > Snap To Guides" in Storyboard. I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this will be helpful, but I just had the same problem and the only thing which worked was re-installing Xcode (7.3) and trashing all of the Xcode preferences.

Good luck.